# Monitor Usage Statistic-- How it is done?

Tags: c#, aop, usage-statistics

Windows, Firefox or Google Chrome all monitor usage statistics and analyze the crash reports are sent to them. I am thinking of implementing the same feature into my application.

Of course it's easy to litter an application with a lot of logging statement, but this is the approach that I want to avoid because I don't want my code to have too many cross cutting concern in a function. I am thinking about using AOP to do it, but before that I want to know how other people implement this feature first.

Anyone has any suggestion?

Clarification: I am working on desktop application, and doesn't involve any RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

In "Debugging .Net 2.0 Applications" John Robbins (of Wintellect) writes extensively about how to generate and debug crash reports (acutally windbg/SOS mini dumps).  His Superassert class contains code to generate these.  Be warned though - there is a lot of effort required to set this up properly: symbol servers, source servers as well as a good knowledge of VS2005 and windbg.  His book, however, guides you through the process.

Regarding usage statistics, I have often tied this into authorisation, i.e. has a user the right to carry out a particular task.  Overly simply put this could be a method like this (ApplicationActions  is an enum):

```
public static bool HasPermission( ApplicationActions action )
{
    // Validate user has permission.
    // Log request and result.
}
```

This method could be added to a singleton SercurityService class.  As I said this is overly simple but should indicate the sort of service I have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Joel had a blog article about something like this - his app(s) trap crashes and then contact his server with some set of details.  I think he checks for duplicates and throws them out.  It is a great system and I was impressed when I read it.

http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/30/UsingFogBUGZtoGetCrashRep.html

We did this at a place I was at that had a public server set up to receive data.  I am not a db guy and have no servers I control on the public internets.  My personal projects unfortunately do not have this great feature yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a quick look at the Logging Application Block that is part of the Enterprise Library.  It provided a large number of the things you require, and is well maintained.  Check out some of the scenarios and samples available, I think you will find them to your liking.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309506.aspx

Comment: EL is rubbish, avoid it at all costs

Comment: Wow, thats a fairly unsubstantiated claim.  I'd agree that many of the application blocks are close to useless, but some have merit.